# menu.findItem returns null with v7 action bar

Tags: java, android

I am learning about action bar in Android Studio from [Android Hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/). Unfortunatelly i use v7 action bar and androidhive use built-in action bar that might makes a little different. The problem is at search view part.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    System.out.println("Search Manager : "+searchManager);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    System.out.println("Search View : "+searchView);
    //searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

mainmenu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

The command line says that the searchView is null.
I have changed android:actionViewClass to app:actionViewClass but it said android.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

For full code, you can see [here](https://github.com/zihadrizkyef/BelajarActionBar)

How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use in

```
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

instead of

```
android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

I hope This would be help you.